# How to update TextView in AlertDialog from some updated string value in another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, textview, android-alertdialog

I have one fragment implementing a sensor event listener. It counts the period of time the sensor has run in a  runnable of the onSensorChange method. When I press a button in the activity an alert dialog box appears. I wish to update the string value of one of the textviews in the alert dialog with how long the sensor event listener has been running.

I've tried sharedPrefs so far and haven't had any success ... the value is never updated

Heres part of the code for the fragment implementing the listener:

```
private class mRecordDataRunnable implements Runnable {
    private SensorEvent event;
    public mRecordDataRunnable(SensorEvent _event) {
        this.event = _event;

    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public void run() {
    mTotalTime = currentTime - pastTime;

    txTotalTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(mTotalTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(mTotalTime) - 
                        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(mTotalTime)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(mTotalTime) - 
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(mTotalTime)));   

    String timeAKey = "com.company.name.timea";

        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.company.name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putString(timeAKey,txTotalTime).apply();
     }
}
```

The code for the alert Dialog:

```
public class DialogFragmentAwake extends DialogFragment {

public interface NoticeDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

NoticeDialogListener mListener;
View view;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();      
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_awake, null))
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.create, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragmentAwake.this);
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
                   mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragmentAwake.this);
               }
           })
           .setTitle(R.string.progress_entry);


    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.company.name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String timeAKey = "com.company.name.timea";

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_awake, null);

    String newtime= prefs.getString(timeAKey, "hour" );
    TextView txTimeA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_amount);
    txTimeA.setText(newtime);




    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}
}
```

my layout for the alert dialog (dialog_fragment_awake.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/time_amount"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"   
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit:**

Here is my new code for writing to the shared preference file:

```
            String timeAKey = "com.company.name.timea";

        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.company.name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putString(timeAKey,txTotalTime).apply();
```

I've checked the shared prefs file and it correctly write the time correctly...

Here is my code for reading from the sharedprefs file and updates the textview:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.company.name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String timeAKey = "com.company.name.timea";

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_awake, null);

    String newtime= prefs.getString(timeAKey, "hour" );
    TextView txTimeA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_amount);
    txTimeA.setText(newtime);
```

It correctly reads the right time ... i used systemout to make sure... but the textview still isnt updated

Comment: are you saying that `txTimeAsleep.setText(timeAKey);` does not work?

Comment: yes it doesn't show anything in the alert dialog

Comment: Debug and check whether you data is correctly storing to the SharedPreferences or not.
Print this string before storing "txTotalTime"

Comment: @SilentKiller When I "step into" after a breakpoint set at "SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();" it opens  DexPathListfindClass(String) ... in the code window. In the code window it says source not found.

Comment: you just need to `System.out.println("txTotalTime : " + txTotalTime);` before storing it to SharedPreferences and check your log that what it print.

Comment: @SilentKiller Thx for the help. I have gotten the program to write to and read from the shared preference files correctly ... please see my edit ... the problem now is the TextView in the alert dialog wont update

Comment: @user3211265 did you get data from SharedPreferences.?

Comment: @SilentKiller yes it both writes and reads to and from the shared preferences correctly... i used systemout in my alert dialog and it gives me the right time. The textview in the alert dialog just wont update

Comment: ok i finally solved it! thx for all the help

Comment: @user3211265: if you solved it please post an answer explaining what you did

Comment: ok i'll post it as soon as i can ... i have to convert my code back tho and rename things